# International Redirect Script Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now. Can someone tell me why it isn't working?

```js
<script src="//j.maxmind.com/app/country.js" charset="ISO-8859-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    var target = new Array(); // Target Array, Don't remove this.

    // Here's an example which redirects visitors to your specified URL for your targeted country code:

    target['All'] = "http://www.mb103.com/lnk.asp?o=5753&c=72626&a=131638&l=4473"; // Redirects non-targeted/other visitors to this URL.
    target['US'] = "http://google.com"; // Redirects' "US" (United States) Visitors to this URL.
    target['GB'] = "http://www.mb01.com/lnk.asp?o=1747&c=26002&a=131638&l=1322"; // Redirects' "GB" (United Kingdom) Visitors to this URL.
    target['CA'] = "http://www.mb102.com/lnk.asp?o=8594&c=918273&a=131638&l=7306"; // Redirects' "CA" (Canada) Visitors to this URL.

    /* == DON'T EDIT THE BELOW CODE == */
     var visitorCountryCode = geoip_country_code();
     var redirectURL = target[visitorCountryCode];
     if(redirectURL == null) redirectURL = target['All'];
     if(redirectURL) window.top.location.href = redirectURL;
    /* == DON'T EDIT THE ABOVE CODE == */
</script>​
```

Comment: Where is the starting `<script>` block?

Comment: `var target = new Array(); target['All'] = ...` There are no associative arrays in javascript only objects

Comment: @abhishekkannojia is correct, but it should be fine in this case as they're not using any of the methods or properties that come with arrays.

Comment: the first line is the starting block.

Comment: @user3147299 Your first line starts a `<script>` and then closes `</script>` the in the first line itself. Rest of the code is lying there without another starting `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `geoip_country_code()` that I think should be available from `//j.maxmind.com/app/country.js` this library. But if you try to access that javascript file manually, directly in your browser, you'll get a 404 error status.

So you are trying to use a function that is not available.

Comment: hmm so what do I do to repair it?

Comment: Why do you need that script ? "//j.maxmind.com/app/country.js"

Comment: redirect traffic based on nationality